# Representation of value class in table

Tags: matlab, matlab-table, matlab-class

If I have a value class like this:

```
classdef MyVal
    properties
        foo
    end
    methods 
        function self = MyVal(varargin)
            if nargin > 0
                self.foo = varargin{1};
            end
        end
    end
end
```

and use it in a table:

```
foo(1) = MyVal(1); foo(2) = MyVal(2);
t = table(foo')
```

the output is:

```
t =

  2×1 table

       Var1    
    ___________

    [1×1 MyVal]
    [1×1 MyVal]
```

Is there any method which has to be defined in `MyVal` (or any property of the table) which allows to change the representation of the value in the table? I do not want to convert the data passed to `table` since I'd like to retrieve instances of `MyVal` when I index in the table.

Comment: Do you just want to see this when displaying the table in the command window? Or also in the workspace?

Comment: In the command window. And, finally, in an `uitable`.

Comment: You probably need to overload `disp` or `display`. Not sure though.

Comment: Neither overloading `disp` nor `display` helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom wrapper for `table`. This is slightly pokey because MATLAB doesn't let you inherit from the `table` class, but by overloading the `subsref` and `subsasgn` operators you can get most of the functionality anyway...

I've included the class at the bottom of this answer since it's a bit long, usage would look like this:

```
>> foo(1) = MyVal(1); foo(2) = MyVal(2);
>> t = MyTable(foo') % Omitting the ";" calls our overloaded "disp" function
t = 
    Var1
    ____
    1   
    2
```

You can also use this to extract the numeric data (i.e. the `foo` property alongside other data) by using `t.numeric`, although I suspect you will need to use `table2array` on this for use with `uitable`, as you would with a normal `table`.

```
classdef MyTable
    properties ( Access = private )
        table_
    end
    properties ( Dependent = true )
        numeric
    end
    methods % Constructor and getter
        function obj = MyTable( varargin )
            % Store as a normal table internally
            obj.table_ = table( varargin{:} );
        end 
        function num = get.numeric( obj )
            % By calling obj.numeric, output the table but with MyVal
            % objects replaced by their "foo" property.
            % This could be passed into a uitable, and is used in disp()
            cls = varfun( @(x)isa(x,'MyVal'), obj.table_, 'OutputFormat', 'uniform' );
            num = obj.table_;
            for ii = find(cls)
                num.(num.Properties.VariableNames{ii}) = [num.(num.Properties.VariableNames{ii}).foo].';
            end            
        end
    end
    methods % Overloaded to emulate table behaviour        
        function disp( obj )
            % Overload the disp function (also called when semi colon is
            % omitted) to output the numeric version of the table
            disp( obj.numeric );
        end
        % Overload subsref and subsasgn for table indexing
        function varargout = subsref( obj, s )
            [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin( 'subsref', obj.table_, s );
        end
        function obj = subsasgn( obj, s, varargin )
            obj.table_ = builtin( 'subsasgn', obj.table_, s, varargin{:} );
        end    
        % Have to overload size and isa for workspace preview
        function sz = size( obj, varargin )
            sz = size( obj.table_, varargin{:} );
        end
        function b = isa( obj, varargin )
            % This is only OK to do because we overloaded subsref/subsasgn
            b = isa( obj.table_, varargin{:} );
        end        
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice, I wanted to suggest that but was too lazy to implement it. Good job adding all the overloads to keep normal functionalities of tables.

Comment: I was thinking about something similar, too. But I usually run into problems when wrapping a sealed class since I do not know which methods to implement to keep the functionality of the class. I don't understand why Matlab prohibits deriving from some (a lot) classes.

Of course, my true value class looks more complex, but I can use the principle.

Answer (score 2):

Only a *half* answer

I couldn't find the way to customise the display of the `table` of object, but if you can get by by using `arrays` of object there is a way, described in [Customize Object Display for Classes](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/custom-object-display.html).

For your example, you have to derive your class with: `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay`, then override the `displayNonScalarObject` method:

```
classdef MyVal < matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay
    properties
        foo
    end
    methods
        function self = MyVal(varargin)
            if nargin > 0
                self.foo = varargin{1};
            end
        end
    end
    
    methods (Access = protected)
        function displayNonScalarObject(objAry)
            dimStr = matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay.convertDimensionsToString(objAry);
            cName = matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay.getClassNameForHeader(objAry);
            headerStr = [dimStr,' ',cName,' members:'];
            header = sprintf('%s\n',headerStr);
            disp(header)
            for ix = 1:length(objAry)
                o = objAry(ix);

                % OPTION 1:
                % For a class with a sinle property, no need to call the
                % big guns, just build your own display:
                disp( [num2str(ix) ': foo = ' num2str(o.foo) ] ) ;
                
                % OR OPTION 2: (comment option1 if you use this)
                % If your class had multiple properties and you want to
                % display several of them, use the MATLAB built-in functions:
                
                % create a structure with the property names you need
                % displayed:
%                 propList = struct('foo',o.foo,'prop2',o.prop2,'prop3',o.prop3);
                % Then let MATLAB handle the display
%                 propgrp = matlab.mixin.util.PropertyGroup(propList);
%                 matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay.displayPropertyGroups(o,propgrp);
            end
        end  
    end
end
```

Now if you build an array of your class, the display will look like:

```
>> foo(1) = MyVal(1); foo(2) = MyVal(2);
>> foo
foo = 
1x2 MyVal members:

1: foo = 1
2: foo = 2
```

Of course this is just an example and is highly customizable. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to make that work for `table` objects.

Comment: The problem with this is that I use `table`s as a poor man's replacement of databases. If one just has some tens of values and uses named rows, this is quite handy.